# Spark : Can i use same accumulator for different transformations?

Tags: java, apache-spark, accumulator

I want to know whether a single accumulator instance can be used for different transformation in spark.

I am using **Spark 1.6.1**, **Java 8**.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494452/when-are-accumulators-truly-reliable not answer your question?

Comment: yes, thanks, the question is not so catchy btw.