# How do I extract the accumulator value in driver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Following is how my code sequenced,

```
//Accumulator initialized 
val count = new LongAccumulator
sparksession.sparkContext.register(count,"count accumulator")

// Streaming Transformation
val DF = fromKafkaDF.map{
  count.add(1)
  println(count.value)  // This value is one
  //some transformation
}.writeStream.outputMode("update").format("console").start()

//trying to access the value of accumulator from driver
println(count.value)  //this value is zero
```

Why the value of accumulator is zero in driver? I have other logic to work on based on this accumulator.
Please suggest.

Comment: My guess is that `println(count.value)` at the end is executed before transformation is executed. Because since you call `start()` the execution will start in background. To check this - try to add sleep for few seconds before.

Comment: I did added Thread.sleep, still the same result. value of count is still zero

Comment: Do you actually see any output from this dataframe?

Comment: yes it does, the counter inside the map operation is working fine and it shows the valid count.

Comment: Try to call `sum()` or `count()` instead of `value`?

Comment: Btw, you could try to use accumulator same as [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-broadcast-variables-and-checkpoints)

Answer (score 0):

For you to accumulate any value in counter, you should perform an action and check, accumulator wont be in use without any action, please check the link [accumulator explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494452/when-are-accumulators-truly-reliable)

Answer (score 0):

use it in listeners like,

```
class TestListner(acc: LongAccumulator) extends StreamingQueryListener {
  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
    println("onQueryStarted   :" + event.toString)
  }

  override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    println(acc)
    acc.reset()
    println("onQueryProgress    :" + event.progress)
  }

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
    println("onQueryProgress    :" + event)
  }
}
```

and addListener in your main application,

```
    spark.streams.addListener(new TestListner(acc))
```